# Changing colour of Toggle Button when clicked and store its clicked state

Tags: android, button, click

In my app read from moviesdb. I can add any of them as favourites and can also unfavourite them. Here is my question though. I want the button to change colour when clicked and be like that until I come back later and unfavourite the movie. Here is the part of the code I want to change. Basically I say if `isChecked` is `true`, I say hey add this movie to the db as favourite. If I clicked it again I delete it.

```
b.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if(isChecked) {

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID, mMovieId);
            contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_POSTER_PATH, mImage);
            contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_TITLE, mTitle);
            contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_OVERVIEW, mOverview);
            contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RELEASE_DATE, mDate);
            contentValues.put(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_VOTE_AVERAGE, mRating);

            uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Movie:  " + mTitle + " was added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }else{

            Uri deleteUri = FavouriteContract.FavouriteEntry.buildMovieUriWithId(mMovieId);

            getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
                          deleteUri,
                          null,
                          null);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Movie deleted from favourites ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Theo.

**UPDATE**

I tried my previous effort and almost fixed it

I created a drawable xml file,

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_black"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_black" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_black"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_star_border" />
```

and I imported it in my ToggleButton.

```
<ToggleButton

            android:id="@+id/add_favourite"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background_selector"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
             />
```

Answer (score 0):

To change Toggle button color you can use a custom background. Create a drawable.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/red"  />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/green"  />
</selector>
```

Now put it on your toggle.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToggleButton"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_toggle"/>
```

now to maintain toggle state you can use SharedPreference.

Comment: Here is the thing. I already have as background as star which is use as ToggleButton.

Answer (score 0):

To make the `ToggleButton` work as an on/off star you will have to make it like this:

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/starButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/some_background_you_want"
        android:button="@drawable/star_selector" <!--place your star selector here-->
        android:textOff="@null" <!--Get rid of the text-->
        android:textOn="@null"  <!--Get rid of the text--> />
```